# TFS 2012 - Configure Reporting after disaster recovery

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs

I tried recovery whole TFS from backup - just to imitate disaster recovery situation.
I backup DBs and then configured TFS with wizard (based on restored Tfs_Configuration database).

But now when I connect to TFS Console and check Reporting I got error:

```
TF246017: Team Foundation server could not connect to the database. 
Verify thath the server that is hosting the database is operational and that network 
problems are not blocking communication with the server.
```

When I click OK I get that everything under Reporting is 'Unknown' and there is no Edit button.

[image]

I noticed also that under Application Tier > Reporting Service Summary > Manager URL and Server URL still points to the old server.

Question: How I can configure Reporting for the new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the first error before you can do anything. If the admin console can't connect to the databases you have not completed a restore as per the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620932.aspx

Follow the documented procedures for both backup and restore.

Comment: Thanks, I reconfigured Reports in Report Server Configuration Tool and it works!